# How to download data on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am looking for a list of all ZIP codes that contain tribal lands. It looks like one was already created and put up on ArcGIS Online here: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=241b01b48db1409381a4e42fe6477821

However, I can't figure out how to actually download the table. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the ArcGIS REST service

https://services.arcgis.com/cJ9YHowT8TU7DUyn/ArcGIS/rest/services/ZipToTribalLookups_WFL/FeatureServer/1/query

```
where:1=1 & Out Fields: *
```

[image]

returns
[image]
https://services.arcgis.com/cJ9YHowT8TU7DUyn/ArcGIS/rest/services/ZipToTribalLookups_WFL/FeatureServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&resultType=none&outFields=*&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&sqlFormat=none&f=pgeojson&token=

please note: **geometry is null**